# How hot should the water be for instant coffee?

Tags: instant

Sometimes I find myself in situations where instant coffee is the only thing available. How hot should the water be when I make it? I'm in Britain, so boil water with an electric kettle. Should I pour just off the boil, or let it wait a bit to cool down?

Answer (score 11):

There's an answer to this question at [Seasoned Advice](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/): see [What water temperature should be used for instant coffee?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/36290/25286)

A brief summary, taken from [@PatrickSebastien's answer](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/36356/25286):

- Use water at whatever temperature you like to drink your coffee at, or
- Use water just below boiling, around 95-99 degrees Celsius (~205-210 F).

Other articles [like this one from WikiHow](http://www.wikihow.com/Make-Better-Tasting-Instant-Coffee) also recommend using filtered water that is just off the boil.

See also that same SA answer, and [this question](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/q/411/262), for a discussion and additional context about how instant coffee powder is produced.

Comment: Good find; thanks for finding and posting that SA question and the other link. Your WikiHow link was broken, and some other things weren't clear; I took the liberty of trimming your answer down to the essentials. I hope you don't mind. +1 for the good find.

Comment: Personal experience - Using _just_ off the boil led to bitterness with a new style of instant coffee (https://www.suddencoffee.com), which is prepared differently than traditional instant coffee.  The combination of dissolving the instant grounds in a few tsp of cold water, then adding hot water _1 minute_ off the boil was much better.