# Volume of water to 2 grams of instant coffee

Tags: instant

I picked up a pack of Kenco Millicano 2 gram sticks to take to college with me because the coffee at the college doesn't taste great and is €1.50 for a tiny cup, so I was wondering in your experience what would be an acceptable volume of water for this mass of coffee?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those sound like single-serving packets; **they are probably intended for a single "cup" of coffee -- somewhere between 150mL - 250mL** (5 fl. oz. - 8 fl. oz), depending on how strong you prefer your coffee. Volumetrically, instant coffee is usually on the order of 5-10 mL (1-2 tsp) coffee powder per cup, and this sounds like it's about the same.

I'd suggest starting with 150mL / 5 fl. oz. and try it. Add more water as necessary. Or, in the event that you like it even stronger, use less water next time. For a strength more like mass-market coffee, you might get up to 350mL cup (10 or 12 fl. oz.).

Aren't there directions on the packet or box? Seems like there should be. If so, I'd use those instead. :)

Comment: ... and welcome to [coffee.se]! You might also be interested in [how instant coffee is made](http://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/411/how-is-instant-coffee-made) or other factors in [preparing instant coffee](http://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/1533/how-hot-should-the-water-be-for-instant-coffee).

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer :) unfortunately there seems to be no volume listed on the packaging, and I only ask since it would be handy to find a travel mug of some description with the volumes you described as they also charge if you just take a disposable cup! I assume they expect a regular mug size so that's why they don't include a recommended volume.! Cheers for the answer :)

Comment: @MrLuke370 Certainly try (brewing a cup into any vessel) before you buy (a mug)!

Comment: Even more, if you tend to drink your coffee with milk, try that as well with you instant coffee and see how much milk you like to add. This may affect the needed volume of the cup as well.