# Why does instant coffee foam when stirring it?

Tags: instant

I have seen that when preparing coffee without milk (just water and coffee), instant coffee (at least Nespresso) foams when stirring it just a bit. However, regular coffee grounds do not.

Does someone know the reason for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have noticed the same thing. I believe it occurs because minute gas particles in the instant coffee, trapped during [the production process](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/q/411), are suddenly released. This gas (air or something inert) rises to the top and bubbles or foams. It dissipates immediately, unlike crema.

I don't think it's caused by any physical chemistry stuff, like heat from dissolution or any actual reaction, though I do notice it more with very hot water.

Answer (score 1):

Both instant coffee and regular ground beans "foam" when pouring hot water over them.

Here you can see a coffee cupping (quality assessment), where they pour fresh off the boil water onto coffee grounds:

[image: Cupping]

Most of the gas released during any kind of coffee brewing is the CO2 created during roasting. While brewing filter coffee (in a V60 for example) this initial phase of degassing is called *the bloom*.

Instant coffee also degases a bit when brewing, here is an extreme example:

[image]

When either of those coffees is left alone for a while all of the trapped gas escapes, similar to a soda which is left open. When the gas has escaped and the "foam" disappeared you cannot create a foam on top again, unless you whisk it really really fast.