# How to make mild instant coffee?

Tags: instant

I've recently become a fan of "Nescafe Food Service bend" Instant coffee (as pictured below). I've had a number of other brands of instant coffee and have been wondering how do they create such a mild blend of instant coffee.  It clearly isn't freeze dried but is agglomerated, this usually gives the coffee more of a bitter taste, but here it is rather smooth.

[image]

How do you make mild agglomerated coffee?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How is instant coffee made?](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/411/how-is-instant-coffee-made)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making instant coffee is the same process as making a cup of coffee from grinding your own beans - at least the first part of it before the drying.

[How is instant coffee made](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/411/how-is-instant-coffee-made)

So if I want a mild cup of coffee, I use less coffee grind. There are other variables that can be played with along with the amount of grind: extraction time, extraction temperature, bean roast level.

You can probably make your cup of instant less mild by adding an extra spoon or so of instant. Simulating (?) more coffee grind.